# Hourly electrical load profile data for domestic home: where to find?

Tags: data, load

I need at least hourly data for individual households' electrical load profile for a renewable energy system model.

I've had a look online and struggled to find such data. For example I've found [this](http://ukerc.rl.ac.uk/DC/cgi-bin/edc_search.pl?GoButton=Detail&WantComp=42&WantResult=&WantText=EDC0000041)

but not only is it 20years old, it looks like it isn't from an individual house.

The UK Household Electricity Survey, which monitored a total of 250 owner-occupier households across England from 2010 to 2011 would be ideal, however the actual data they collected I can't find.

Their report, [here](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/household-electricity-survey--2) shows the report etc, but not the actual data.

Where might I find the actual electrical usage of a household? Could energy companies provide this?

Comment: Measure your own.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Unfortunately it needs to be for an entire year, so using my own wouldn't be viable at this stage.

Comment: I am SURE it depends a lot on the location of the home. In places where it gets warm in the summer, there will be very large peaks due to air-conditioning load, for example. These peaks are good candidates for localized solar, since the demand and supply are co-incident.

Comment: Data for one individual household is not very useful to anyone except that individual. Even one's own data for last year may be of limited use this year if circumstances have changed. It is very unlikely that you will find anything more than an average for a number of households. Even that may be hard to find since most such data is a mix of households, commercial, and industrial users. Are you looking for data any any particular part of the world?

Comment: You could see if there is "typical" data provided with software like RETScreen. http://www.nrcan.gc.ca/energy/software-tools/7465 that and others are available for free download.

Comment: @CharlesCowie UK data would be preferred, or somewhere where there is no need for air-conditioning as mentioned above. The electricity used should exclude any heating/cooling of the house.

The data in the second link is from 250 households, so if I was able to find the data from each that would be what I'm looking for.

Comment: You can investigate the source of the data you have to see if you can get the raw data. You could look a your own household in detail and think about what you may do differently on some days or some months of the year. I know RETScreen has some examples. When I looked at it it was mostly concerned with a bigger picture, but I know they have issued a major revision since I looked at it. The US government has something similar. It would be worth checking the US Energy Information Agency.

Comment: RETScreen required a Windows PC and MS Excel when I used it,  but it worked on a Mac with Parallels.

Comment: Check the website of your power service , Ours gives hourly data with our smart meters with my account & ID. Recently they sent me a letter to show I used twice the avearge in my neighbourhood and 3x the leanest user consumption ,so I am planning to measure each breaker with a data logger to find the cost of each load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone going through the pain of trying to find such data comes across this question, I managed to find a good dataset which has half hourly consumption rates for individual houses (over 5500) in London.

- [SmartMeter Energy Consumption Data in London Households](https://data.london.gov.uk/dataset/smartmeter-energy-use-data-in-london-households)

The dataset is huge, about 168 million rows of data, so you'll need to find a good way to analyse it and find what you need. There are smaller fills containing the same data broken up in the link, but they are still pretty big.

Comment: The data are in csv files, which can be read by Excel, but which are NOT Excel files.  You would probably do better to analyse the data using a better tool that does not load the whole file into memory at once.  Matlab or R or something along those lines.  The data files are some 10GB in total - working with that much data in Excel could best be described as "painful." Scipy would also be a good tool for handling that much data.

Comment: I've edited to remove excel. I found out the hard way that excel wouldn't cope. I wouldn't describe it as painful, or anything, it simply took too long to load and I closed it. Regarding matlab however, I am struggling to look at the data without importing it.